# How to dynamically draw and animate lines between circles in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have following dropdown menu.

```
    <form action="" method="get" id="myForm">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Select Type of Casting</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="castingSelection">
          <option value="Unicast">Unicast</option>
          <option value="Multicast">Multicast</option>
          <option value="BroadCast">Broadcast</option>
          <option value="Anycast">Anycast</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <!-- simulate -->
      <input type="submit" value="Simulate" class="btn btn-danger">
    </form>
```

I want the user to select type of casting they want to simulate and based on what they select I want to draw lines between circles. My d3 code till now is

```
<script>
var canvas = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 1200)
  .attr("height", 720)
  .attr("color", "black");

// create the main server
function createMainServer(xindex, yindex, radius){
    var circle = canvas.append("circle")
            .attr("fill", "purple")
            .attr("cx", xindex)
            .attr("cy", yindex)
            .attr("r", radius)
}
// create the destination server 
function createDots(xindex, yindex, radius){
    // create the circle
    var circle = canvas.append("circle")
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .attr("cx", xindex)
        .attr("cy", yindex)
        .attr("r", radius);  
}
createMainServer(150, 300, 25)
createDots(650, 200, 25)
createDots(650, 100, 25)
createDots(650, 400, 25)
createDots(650, 300, 25)
createDots(650, 500, 25)
```

I have created the dots, what I want for now is to let user select type of casting and if its unicast, then the main server draws line to any one of other circles(computers).

Comment: to draw lines, you can use `.append("lines")` ... for animation, use d3 transition